# Read digits as individual digit from a big number

Tags: c

How can I read a digit as single digit within a number?

```
int main() {
long long int num1;
printf("enter number: ");
scanf("%lld", &num1);
```

for example if user input is 123456789, how can I use 4 as a single digit?

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "digit" in a "number",  For example, decimal "123" == octal "723" - is the first digit "1" or "7"?  Perhaps you mean a character string, like "0x31323300" (for the ASII characters "1", "2" and "3")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `scanf()` call in the question uses the `%lld` specifier, which interprets input in base ten, we can assume you want digits in base ten. Assuming the number is positive:

1. First divide by a power of ten. To extract the sixth digit from the right, divide by a power of 10 that has six digits, such as `100000`. This gives 1234. If you want to retrieve a variable digit, you can use repeated division by 10 to move the correct digit into the one's place, as shown in [Ashiquzzaman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34113217/2738262). If you instead want digits from the left, start by counting digits in the number: divide it by 10 until the quotient is zero.
2. Use the modulo operator `%` to extract the remainder from division by 10. This gives 4.

If the number is negative, [division in C rounds toward zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602857/2738262). This means `-123456789` will produce `-1234` after the first step and `-4` after the second.

Comment: @paulsm4 it's not a silly question. I am new to C, so give me a break. =)

Comment: OK, Batool.  But do you get that there's really no absolute meaning as to a "digit" in a "number"?  Do you get that *all* of the responses you got (as well as several other, different responses you might have gotten) are "correct" .... depending on how you define the problem?  As a character in a string, as a result in a base-ten arithmetic expression ... or perhaps as "something else" entirely?  It really has nothing to do with "C" ... and everything to do with "understanding computing".

Comment: @paulsm4 There's an absolute meaning when the question's `scanf()` call uses an explicitly decimal specifier `"%lld"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take input as `long long int` then extract the digit as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int getDigit(long long number, int idx)
{
    number = abs(number);
    while(idx--)
        number/=10;
    return number%10;
}
int main()
{
    long long int num1;
    int indexOfDigit = 4;
    printf("enter number: ");
    scanf("%lld", &num1);
    printf("%d\n", getDigit(num1, indexOfDigit));
}
```

Sample input: `123456789`

Sample Output: `5`

**For Explanation** see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34113206/2317535) of [tepples](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2738262/tepples)

Answer (score 0):

Read it as a sequence of chars (basically, as if it were a string), using %c in scanf in a loop until EOF is read

```
int main()
{
  int digit;

  printf("enter number: ");
  digit = getchar();
  while (digit != EOF)
  {
    /* Process digit */
    digit = getchar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the input as a char* and access to the digits with char[3] for the fourth digit?